# Spring Security @PreAuthorize access to autowired bean using SpEL language

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, annotations, spring-el

I want to access to my autowired bean under the Spring Security @PreAuthorize using SpEL language.

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class TodoDao implements ITodoDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade;

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("...") // I want to access to one of my autowired bean here
    public void changeTodoStatus(Todo todo) {
        Object user = authenticationFacade.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        todo.setDone(!todo.isDone());
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(todo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use '@' before your bean name:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class TodoDao implements ITodoDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade;

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("@authenticationFacade.(#toDo)") // I want to access to one of my autowired bean here
    public void changeTodoStatus(Todo todo) {
        Object user = authenticationFacade.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        todo.setDone(!todo.isDone());
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(todo);
    }
}
```